# sort array in asssembly code and stack pointer

Tags: assembly, mips, stack-memory

i made program , for sorting array and print original position of the number in array 
for example **10,5,3,15,21,14**
for *3rd* position will return **14** and **6** th place (number **14** position in original array)

Im trying to sort array of six using `bubble sort` in assembly
the array can be sorted correctly but Im having trouble with stack pointer
i use stack pointer to store the original array, as i need to know the original position before sorting. but when I tried to load lw **$t0,0($sp)** in loops function, **$t0** give **0**,what is wrong **?** and how can I access each element in stack pointer
however, i can correctly load the $sp, after i changed 
lw $t0,-24($sp) to this in loop function, why cant i retrieve value using 0($sp)?

```
loops: ##this part causing trouble
lw $t0,0($sp) ##but when jump to this, the stack pointer give 0 in $t0 why?
addi $sp,$sp,4
addi $t7,$t7,1
beq $t8,$t0,koko
j loops







.text
.globl main


main:
la $t1,array ##copy base address of array to t1
lw $t0,num ##copy num to t0
lw $s3, num ##stop =6
##lw $t2,0($t1)

li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt
syscall


li $v0,5
syscall
move $s0,$v0 ##user input


addi $t6,$0,0
sub $t9,$s3,$s0 ## 6-3
addi $t3,$t3,1

addiu $sp,$sp,-32 ## here im made stack,
jal shokika
j loops ##go to here after return from end:

shokika:  ##use to store original array
lw $t2,0($t1)
bge $t6,6,outer
sw $t2,0($sp)
addi $t1,$t1,4
addi $sp,$sp,4
addi $t6,$t6,1
j shokika

loops:
lw $t0,0($sp) ##but when jump to this, the stack pointer give 0 in $t0 why?
addi $sp,$sp,4
addi $t7,$t7,1
beq $t8,$t0,koko
j loops

outer:
la $t1,array
la $sp,0($sp)
addi $s3,$s3,-1 ##5
ble $s3,$zero,end
li $s0,0 ##inner loop counter
li $s1,0 ##outer counter


inner:
bge $s0,$s3,inner_end
lw $t3,0($t1) ##cur elem
lw $t4,4($t1) ## next el
addi $s0,$s0,1
ble $t4,$t3, swap
addi $t1,$t1,4

j inner

inner_end:
la $t1,array
j outer

swap:
sw $t3,4($t1)
sw $t4,0($t1)
addi $t1,$t1,4
j inner


end:
addi $t5,$0,4
mul $t5,$t5,$t9 ##4*3
add $t9,$t5,$t1 ##t1 base address arr
lw $t8,0($t9) ##sort
jr $ra

koko:

li $v0,4
la $a0,result
syscall

li $v0,1
move $a0,$t7 ##position
syscall

li $v0,4
la $a0,sort
syscall

li $v0,1
move $a0,$t8 ##psort
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall


.data 
array:
.word 10,5,3,15,21,14
array2:
.space 400
num:
.word 6
sort: .asciiz "$s2->"
result: .asciiz "$s1->"
prompt: .asciiz "$s0->"
```

Comment: Do *not* modify sp to copy your array. sp should only be changed at the start and end of a procedure. Think of what would happen if you have an interrupt that needs stack space... This is also the cause of the problem in your code.  When you exit the 'shokika' loop, sp has been added 6*4 in the loop and points to garbage.

Comment: @AlainMerigot thanks but if i write -24 , im able to go back to 0($sp) ,but this is not efficient?

Comment: Just do not use sp. Copy sp to another register to do the array copy.